# Mass adjust materials after import using python?

Tags: python, materials

So I am currently testing out the new google city API for blender and I've been able to import an entire scene for a project. The problem is the material for the mesh comes in as 100s of tiles with individual materials assigned to them. The materials nodes aren't done correctly and going in and changing each individual material would be impossible[image: here is what I have]

and here is what I would like
[image]

is there any possibility to do this en masse using python? I have used scripts, but for other programs like Rhino. Thanks and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do that. I assume the material layout given in your screenshots is the same for all materials used by one object. Try this script:

```
import bpy

# get google obj
obj = bpy.data.objects['<google>'] # replace with real name

# look at all materials in this object
for material in obj.data.materials:
    
    nodes = material.node_tree.nodes # the shader nodes
    links = material.node_tree.links # the node noodles
    
    # find our needed nodes
    for node in nodes:
        if node.type == 'TEX_IMAGE':
            img_tex_node = node
        elif node.type == 'OUTPUT_MATERIAL':
            mat_output_node = node

    # create the diffuse bsdf node and noodle all together
    diffuse_bsdf_node = nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse')

    links.new(img_tex_node.outputs['Color'], diffuse_bsdf_node.inputs['Color'])
    links.new(diffuse_bsdf_node.outputs['BSDF'], mat_output_node.inputs['Surface'])
    
    # remove all others
    unused_nodes = [ n for n in nodes if n.type != 'TEX_IMAGE' and n.type != 'OUTPUT_MATERIAL' and n.type != 'BSDF_DIFFUSE' ]
    for node in unused_nodes:
        nodes.remove(node)
```

Comment: Genius. Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome, happy scripting.